# Bootstrap transparent navbar with coloured collapse

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm having problems with my transparent navbar. The problem is that I wanted to make the links not transparent when viewed from mobile.

This is what is happening in mobile.

[image]

I wanted to make something like this when viewed only in mobile. I still want to have a fully transparent navbar when viewed in large screens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, found the answer.
Just put this code in style

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar {background: rgb(184, 132, 132);}
}
```